# Parametrizing a fermion bilinear for $N_f=2$

Tags: symmetry, representation-theory, fermions

In https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9210253 the possible values for a fermion bilinear $ M=\bar{\psi_{L,i}} \psi_{R,j} $ with $i,j=1,2$ are parameterized in terms of pauli matrices as $M= \sigma \mathbb{I}+i \vec{\pi}\cdot \vec{\tau}$ where $\vec{\tau}$ are the Pauli matrices. However, this is not the most general parameterization since it restricts to $\det{M}>0$ (I know why they do this, assume I am interested in the different case where the $U_A(1)$ somehow isn't broken.). What is the most general parameterization of $M$? Can $M$ be any real matrix, i.e $GL(2,R)$ or complex $GL(2,C)$. Or are there other constraints? Should it be an $SU(2)$ matrix for example? (If so how do I show that?)

To clarify the left-handed and right-handed fermions should transform as a fundamental of $U_{R,L}(2)$ respectively and so $M$ transforms as $M \to U^\dagger M V $ with $U,V \in U(2)$.